# What are the formulas governing blender's exponential easing for animation fcurves?

Tags: fcurves

I was trying to animate something that was scaling exponentially, so I created an fcurve with two keyframes and configured it for exponential easing.  It did not behave as I expected.

Consider two keyframes (frame,value): (1,1) and (11,32).

I would expect that to be interpolated as (3,2) (5,4) (7,8) (9,16) , doubling every two frames.

Instead I see (3,1.121) (5,1.484) (7,2.938) (9,8.75) .

What are the equations governing blender's exponential interpolation mode?

Comment: I expect the math you are looking for can be [found here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/blenlib/intern/easing.c$252)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The math used can be [found here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/blenlib/intern/easing.c$252), the calculations for the parameters used can be [found here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/fcurve.c$2306).

The calculation used for exponential ease in is -

```
change * powf(2, 10 * (time / duration - 1)) + begin
```

The curve is calculated between a start keyframe (`begin`) and an end keyframe, `time` is the time elapsed since the start key and `duration` is the total time between start and end, `change` is the amount the keyed value changes between keyframes.

[The commit](https://developer.blender.org/rBdaccaa713b6e66af4b958fa373b31d557a4caa33) that adds this and the other nine interpolation types to blender contains links to [easings.net](http://easings.net) and [robertpenner.com/easing/](http://robertpenner.com/easing/) as the source of the calculations.

Comment: When I reproduce that formula in a spreadsheet it matches the values I'm seeing.  It is somewhat disappointing that the span of the exponent is hardcoded to 1:1024 .

Comment: Feel free to submit a bug report that it should be improved or have alternate interpolation options added.

Comment: When I get some time I think I'll write a math paper about exploiting the fcurve handles to implement an exp(ax+b)+c+dx interpolation, or come up with another formula.

Comment: My incomplete research is documented at http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/math-papers/exponential-easing/exponential-easing.html .  There is considerable work to be done before it can be used as a form of easing in fcurves.